# Is this a risk of SQL injection or a security risk in general?

Tags: c#, sql, security, sql-injection, dapper

I am using Dapper to write SQL queries and have written a generic repository. Seeing as parameterized table names are not supported, I am trying to figure out the best / safest way to dynamically change my table names depending on the implementation of the generic repository.

Originally I thought that I would just pass the table name as a string in the repositories constructor, but that seemed like I was delegating the responsibility of not passing a malicious string to the child class so I opted instead to get the table name directly from a custom attribute.

```
public class TableAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public TableAttribute(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

}
```

Then, on my database models, I would set them as follows:

```
[Table("StudyType")]
public class StudyTypeModel
{

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string TypeName { get; set; }

}
```

Then in my generical repository, I would directly access these attributes:

```
public abstract class GeneralRepository<T> : IGeneralRepository<T>
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _config;
    
    private string _tableName = typeof(T).GetCustomAttribute<TableAttribute>()?.Name ?? throw new Exception("No Table Attribute found.");
    public GeneralRepository(IConfiguration config)
    {
        _config = config;
    }

    public async virtual Task<ICollection<T>> GetAllAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            using IDbConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_config.GetConnectionString("Default"));
    
            var parameters = new { TableName = _tableName };
    
            var query = $"""
                SELECT *
                FROM {_tableName}
                """;
    
            var result = (await connection.QueryAsync<T>(query, parameters)).ToList();
    
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    ... more generic methods
```

I know that you generally want to use parameterized queries, but unfortunately I don't believe this is possible in this scenario. I want to avoid rewriting basic CRUD methods for every table, but I definitely do not want that to come at the expense of application security. Is this a security risk / bad practice?

Thanks.

Comment: SQL injection is generally an issue when you are accepting SQL code as input from the user. If you're using a value from the application, as long as a malicious user couldn't change that value or add a new value, e.g. use a class of their own with an attribute containing malicious SQL code, then you should be fine. You might even validate that value, i.e. check the database to make sure the value matches the name of a table.

Comment: `QUOTENAME` is the safest. But I'd recommend you don't do any of this. Create proper static queries. If you need such dynamic queries, use an ORM such as EF Core.

Comment: But why... Why do you have the need to dynamically use one table or another? There's something off in your database design.

Comment: "...Is this a security risk / bad practice?" -- Oh yes, it is.

Comment: @TheImpaler - It's not about my database design. I'm just trying to avoid writing GetAll(), GetById(), Create(), and Delete() Queries for every single table in my database when the only difference between every query is the table name. That is why I'm drawn to a generic repository, but I understand this may not be optimal from a security standpoint.

Comment: @Charlieface - Thanks for the advice! So if one is against using an ORM, would you say writing GetAll, GetById, and Delete methods for every table is just a necessary inconvenience? I am new to web apps in general, and I trying to follow "Do not repeat yourself", but I understand this may be an exception to that rule.

Comment: @TheImpaler - The approach I took to this was to create a repository for each table, for example: UserRepository, and Inherit GeneralRepository<UserModel>. That way, my UserRepository would contain all the basic CRUD methods, as well as any other necessary methods relating to the User table. I enforced this by making sure the generic repository was abstract. Does my reasoning make any sense?

Comment: Okay, you're against ORM in general, that's fine. But I will suggest at least having a look at _micro-ORM_ (e.g. Dapper is one of the better ones, released by StackOverflow themselves). They're really thin, and does the mapping and sanitising for you so you don't have to do it by hand.

Comment: @NPras May I ask you a question? How do you suppose for new developers to appear, able to write a Dapper-like application?

Comment: As @jmcilhinney mentioned, you don't really have a risk of sql injection with that code, as the modified sql will be coming from the classes that you create. Just as a side note, that try-catch is not necessary unless you are going to do something with the exception before throwing.

Comment: you can use https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper.Contrib

Comment: You are basically recreating an ORM, but badly. I suggest you use an existing one. if you want high performance without much of the tracking faff then I agree Dapper.Contrib is a good option.

Comment: @AkalankaDissanayake - Thanks, I think this is the solution to my problem. It allows me to write my own SQL, but also exposes common SQL queries for CRUD apps.